# How to search only for folders in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, windows-search

In Vista file explorer, how can I use the search to find only directories matching my input?

The find is quite useful and convenient, but I cannot find a way to restrict the result list to directory items as I could in XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write `kind:folders` in search box on top right then start typing directory name like this

`kind:folders test`