# How to filter out folder items in Windows search under Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-search, file-search

I want to search for files in an entire directory tree, but I don't want to see folders in the results. I want to see only files.

How can I exclude folders from showing up in the results under Windows Vista?

Comment: Here's the opposite: [How to search only for folders in Vista](http://superuser.com/questions/41518/how-to-search-only-for-folders-in-vista?rq=1)

Comment: The marked duplicate is labelled as if it's only for Windows 7, but it contains all the info you need for Vista as well (short version `kind: files`).

Comment: I just realized that this is language dependent. You have to adapt those textual options to your Windows language.